# R Batch mode - Can't execute script

Tags: r, csv, batch-processing

To run R non-interactively I've decided to use Batch processing (using Windows 7).
What I've entered the command prompt (CMD)

```
cd c:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64 #set directory
"c:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64\R.exe" CMD BATCH "c:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\myscript.R" "c:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\output.out"
```

The output was generated. I've opened the output.out file and the following error message is visible:

```
> myData1<-read.csv("myData.csv",header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
> temp<-read.csv("Temperature.csv",header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
Calls: read.csv -> read.table -> file
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Temperature.csv': No such file or directory
Execution halted
```

Within the myscript.R file, I've already set the working directory to where the files (myData.csv and Temperature.csv) are located. When I execute the content of myscript.R in Rstudio, it all works. Somehow this error keeps popping up and I am totally clueless. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example you are trying to look for csv file in the `cd c:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.3\bin\x64`.

You need to execute `R.exe` or even better `Rscript.exe` in the directory where `myData.csv` is located.

R exe dir is one thing.
R script dir is another.
csv dir is another.

Use absolute paths or...
Considering you have your R script in the same directory as csv file you can use kind of:

```
CD /path_to_R_script/
path_to_exe/exe script
```

So you run the exe from the directory where you have csv file.

In linux it could look like:

```
cd /my/path && Rscript myscript.R
```

Comment: You sir deserve a cookie. I changed my directory to the where my files are located as you suggested. The other part of the code was still correct.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting Michael Lundholm's pdf `Working with R in batch mode:
Some notes for beginners`

> Although R is installed, the Windows system does not find the file
>   R.exe. This is because this file is in a directory which is not in the
>   default search path of Windows. The reason is that the default
>   behaviour of the installation script is to install new version of R in
>   different directories. It is up to the user to decide where Windows
>   should look for R (i.e., which version to use).
>
> If this error message occurs we have to change the search path so that
>   it includes the path to the directory where R.exe is. We do this as
>   follows:
>
> 1. Open the Control Panel, choose ‘System’, click on ‘Advanced system settings’ in the menue to the left and choose the ‘Environment
>      variables’ button; see Figure 5.
> 2. Choose the variable ‘Path’ and click on the Edit–button. Now we have to edit  Variable value’ so that it also contains the path to the
>      directory where the  various R binaries (programs) are installed.
> 3. The path to this file is found in Windows explorer by looking for the  directories were R was installed. See Figure 6. Typically the
>      path is something like `C:\Program Files\R\R-2.15.1\bin\x64` and it
>      should be appended to the  already existing path in ‘Variable value’.
> 4. Note that the various paths in the search path as separated with a semi–colon so we should add an initial ‘;’ to the string characters
>      that we append to ‘Variable value’. The result can be seen in Figure
>      7.

Once you've added the path to the environment variables, you call Rscript from the directory your csv file is stored in

```
Rscript myscript.R arg1 arg2 arg3
```

or you change the path of

```
 temp <- read.csv("Temperature.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
```

in the `R` file to

```
 temp <- read.csv("C:/Users/.../Temperature.csv", header=T, sep=";", dec=",")
```